# How to add additional headers in https proxy?

Tags: http, ssl, go, https, proxy

I created on golang double HTTP proxy server. Server receives request, adds additional headers in this request and sends this changed request to another proxy server, which read this headers, remove it from request, and finally make request into destination.

With HTTP it works perfect. But how create this with HTTPS ?!

In HTTPS request browser send http CONNECT request, and then send encrypted data. Can i decrypted this data with CA signed server certificate, then add headers, send HTTPS request to another server, and then send HTTPS request to destination !?

Comment: Yes you can. It's the exact same process as an http proxy, but you use a TLS listener. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @JimB So, i created server which listen "TLS port". However, the browser is still sending CONNECT method. What's next ? 
If not too much trouble, can you show the sample code ?! Preferably on golang :) !?

Comment: I'm not sure what to show you. If you can already handle CONNECT in your proxy, changing the underlying protocol to TLS shouldn't affect how you handle the request. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think Jim's saying to use `http.ListenAndServeTLS` so the client establishes a secure session *to your proxy*, you see content and can add headers, vs. what you're currently doing by listening on the socket directly and forwarding the CONNECT and so on back and forth.

Comment: @twotwotwo Thx for your answer. What about certificate ?
For example. Browser request https://google.com with use my proxy. I decrypt this message with my self-signed certificate or with some CA signed certificate. Then browser show me error иecause my certificate, but rather the fingerprint does not match the one that is registered for the google.com and browser show me thet is untrusted connection. Or I'm wrong ?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes clients load a CA certificate that effectively allows the proxy to impersonate any Web site. You can only do this with some arrangement like that; from SSL's perspective, adding a header is no different from replacing the Google login screen with a phishing page.

Comment: Sometimes ? What do you mean :) ? That is, the browser chrome or firefox, give me a warning, and for example curl react normally ?

Comment: Businesses sometimes set up their machines to trust their firewall, which decrypts SSL connections then starts its own SSL connection to the outside world. That is, they actually tell their machines to allow the firewall to perform a man-in-the-middle-attack--otherwise, by design, it's impossible.

Comment: @sintanial did you solve this problem, if yes and If not too much trouble, can you show the sample code, thx

Comment: @Aziz it's impossible (can only if remote server trusted all certificate include self-signed ;)

Comment: @sintanial i see, thx :)